# Trigger vs Oracle Materialized View Log

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `person` with columns of interest

```
id, ab_num, is_valid_act
```

The `is_valid_act` data is being modified by users many times.

We have been asked to build a service for a team that will only give them the changes that are happening on a `is_valid_act` column from `person` table and they can call X times a day.

The initial thought was to create a new table with the `id, person_id, ab_num, is_valid_act`. Then have a trigger for any time the `person.is_valid_act` column is modified.
Then the service can get the records where `id > then the last id` the other team is passing out. And we would manually seed their database.

But we worry about table becoming so big that they will lose performance.

Also, we could use the `date` based but we feel it like that could be error prone.

Another idea is to create a **materialized view** which only will get the newest records with **Materialized View Log**.

Any thought/ideas which way is better to go with?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see how you would write a materialized view that would answer this question unless you are not interested in the history of changes just the most recent change per row.  You could just create a materialized view log and have the service consume the log entries-- that is possible but not officially supported.  A trigger and a log table seems like a much more sensible option.  Be aware, though, that the `id > last id read` approach has the potential to miss rows if the transaction that inserts `id` N happens to commit before the transaction that inserts `id` N-1.

Comment: "...we worry about table becoming so big that they will lose performance..." -- with the proper index it won't lose performance even if the table gets really big. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood all correctly, but for me it looks like you want to implement SCD2 or SCD4: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension or even some kind of temporal validity: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/temporal-validity-12cr1